# Python: Using nougat-ocr in spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, ocr, spyder

I have an issue when using metas nougat-ocr. This feels like a very basic question and I assume that the answer is that I run it from the wrong place.

I have installed it using `pip install nougat-ocr` in spyder. This worked fine, there was no error message. Yet, when I use the following command the way it is described in the documentation

```
$ nougat path/to/file.pdf -o output_directory
```

I get a syntax error.

The same happens when I use the command in the console and from the python application itself. I have tried using a string for the path, that did not help either.

Can anyone spot the mistake I am making?

KR

Comment: Looks like `nougat-ocr` is meant to be run from the command line, not run from a python script or similar. If you need to run it from a python script, the easiest solution might be to do `os.system("nougat path/to/file.pdf -o output_directory")`

Comment: Hm, for me that just opens adobe reader which then tells me that a pdf with the name "nougat.py" has not been found.